# Two issues: images on the top fixed header is larger then header & two sections do not start from first element

Tags: javascript, html, css

**First Issue**

Managed to get fixed sidebar and fixed header. But the issue is I put 3 images on the top fixed header and for some reason on mobile devices its fine but on other resolutions even though images are responsive they get way to large and do not fit in the fixed header.

**Second Issue**

I did manage to make section with javascript but when I scroll down in a section and the select an other item from the left sidebar that section starts from where the last section scroll was left. Doesn't start from the first element of the section. Also even though depending on the resolution I should have 4, 2 or 1 image on a page it does not work.

---

WEBSITE: https://www.cevdetarkun.com/ho3/

### HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" lang="tr">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <title> Hakkioglu Izgara Kofte </title>
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Poppins:300,400,500,600,700,800,900" rel="stylesheet">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://pro.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.15.1/css/all.css">
        <link rel="Stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
        <link rel="Stylesheet" href="css/normalize.css">


    </head>
  
    <body style="overflow: hidden;">
    
<div id="sidebar">
    <nav id="sidebar" class="active">   
        
        <ul class="list-unstyled components">
        <li><a href="index.html" class="logo"><img src="images/logo.png" alt=""></a></li>
        <li style="color:white;">------------------</li>
        <li style="color:white;">-MENÜMÜZ-</li> 
        <li style="color:white;">------------------</li>
        
          <li>
            <a id=izgaralar href="#izgaralar"><span class="fas fa-shish-kebab"></span> Izgaralar</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a id=pideler href="#pideler"><span class="fas fa-soup"></span> Pideler</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a id=hamburgerler href="#hamburgerler"><span class="fas fa-cheeseburger"></span> Hamburgerler</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a id=suluyemekler href="#suluyemekler"><span class="fas fa-salad"></span> Sulu Yemekler</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a id=salatalar href="#salatalar"><span class="fas fa-salad"></span> Salatalar</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a id=tatlilar href="#tatlilar"><span class="fas fa-pie"></span> Tatlilar</a>
          </li>
          
          
          <li style="color:white;">-----------------</li>


        </ul>
        
    </nav>
</div>
        
    
<div id="rightSideWrapper">
            
        <div id="header"> 
        
    
<div class="headerrow">
    
  
  <div class="headercolumn">
  <a href="http://maps.google.com/?q=Büyükdere Cd. No:28/B, 34394 Şişli/İstanbul" target="_blank">
    <img src="images/1.jpg" alt="" style="width:100%">
    </a>
  </div>
  
   <div class="headercolumn">
   
  <a href="tel:05322812329">
    <img src="images/2.jpg" alt="" style="width:100%">
    </a>
  </div>
  
  <div class="headercolumn">

    <img src="images/3.jpg" alt="" style="width:100%">

  </div>
  
    
    </div>      
    
            
            
    <!--Main content-->
<div class="ContentBox" style="display: flex; flex-direction: column; height: 100%;">
    

<section id="main-content" style="flex:1; overflow-y: scroll;">
<div class="row">

    <div class="column">
    <div class="content">
      <h2>Hosgeldiniz</h2>
     <h4>Hakkioglu izgara kofte olarak sizlere en iyi hizmeti sunma icin calisiyoruz...</h4>
    </div>
    </div>
    <div class="column">
    <div class="content">
         <h3>Etlerimiz</h3>
         <h4>Kendi Uretimiziz olup bursadan ozel olarak getirilmektedir.</h4>
         <h4>%100 dana etidir</h4>
    </div>
    </div>
    <div class="column">
    <div class="content">
      <h3>Komur atesi</h3>
        <h4>Urunlerimiz komur atesinde izgarada pisirilmektedir.</h4>
    </div>
    </div>
    
    <div class="column">
    <div class="content">
      <h3>Komur atesi</h3>
        <h4>Urunlerimiz komur atesinde izgarada pisirilmektedir.</h4>
    </div>
    </div>
  
</div>
</section>


 
  <!-- IZGARALAR  -->      
<section id="izgaralar-content"> 
<div class="row">
     
  <div class="column">
    <div class="content">
      <img src="images/urunler/izgaralar/Izgara_kofte.jpg" alt="Izgara Kofte" style="width:100%">
      <h3>Izgara Kofte</h3>
      <h4>1 porsiyon 35 TL</h4>
      <h4>1.5 porsiyon 45 TL</h4>      
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <div class="content">
      <img src="images/urunler/izgaralar/Kasarli_Kofte.jpg"  alt="" style="width:100%">
      <h3>Kasarli Kofte</h3>
     <h4>1 porsiyon 35 TL</h4>
      <h4>1.5 porsiyon 45 TL</h4>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <div class="content">
      <img src="images/urunler/izgaralar/acili_kofte.jpg" alt="" style="width:100%">
      <h3>Acili Kofte</h3>
     <h4>1 porsiyon 35 TL</h4>
      <h4>1.5 porsiyon 45 TL</h4>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <div class="content">
      <img src="images/urunler/izgaralar/Et_Sis.jpg" alt="" style="width:100%">
      <h3>Et Sis</h3>
      <h4>1 porsiyon...35 TL</h4>
      <h4>1.5 porsiyon...45 TL</h4>
    </div>
  </div>
    <div class="column">
    <div class="content">
      <img src="images/urunler/izgaralar/Antrikot.jpg" alt="" style="width:100%">
      <h3>Antrikot</h3>
      <h4>1 porsiyon...35 TL</h4>
      <h4>1.5 porsiyon...45 TL</h4>
    </div>
  </div>
    <div class="column">
    <div class="content">
      <img src="images/urunler/izgaralar/pirzola.jpg" alt="" style="width:100%">
      <h3>Pirzola</h3>
      <h4>1 porsiyon...35 TL</h4>
      <h4>1.5 porsiyon...45 TL</h4>
    </div>
  </div>
    <div class="column">
    <div class="content">
      <img src="images/urunler/izgaralar/Sucuk_Izgara.jpg" alt="" style="width:100%">
      <h3>Sucuk Izgara</h3>
    <h4>1 porsiyon 35 TL</h4>
      <h4>1.5 porsiyon 45 TL</h4>
    </div>
  </div>
    <div class="column">
    <div class="content">
      <img src="images/urunler/izgaralar/tavuk_sis.jpg"  alt="" style="width:100%">
      <h3>Tavuk Sis</h3>
     <h4>1 porsiyon 35 TL</h4>
      <h4>1.5 porsiyon 45 TL</h4>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <div class="content">
      <img src="images/urunler/izgaralar/tavuk_pirzola.jpg" alt="" style="width:100%">
      <h3>Tavuk Pirzola</h3>
     <h4>1 porsiyon 35 TL</h4>
      <h4>1.5 porsiyon 45 TL</h4>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <div class="content">
      <img src="images/urunler/izgaralar/tavuk_izgara.jpg" alt="" style="width:100%">
      <h3>Tavuk Izgara</h3>
     <h4>1 porsiyon 35 TL</h4>
      <h4>1.5 porsiyon 45 TL</h4>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <div class="content">
      <img src="images/urunler/izgaralar/Karısık_Izgara.jpg" alt="" style="width:100%">
      <h3>Karisik Izgara</h3>
     <h4>1 porsiyon 35 TL</h4>
      <h4>1.5 porsiyon 45 TL</h4>
    </div>
  </div>
  
</div>
</section>
       
       
   <!-- PIDELER  -->            
<section id="pideler-content">


<div class="row">

  <div class="column">
    <div class="content">
      <img src="images/urunler/pideler/Kasarli_Pide_v2.jpg" alt="" style="width:100%">
      <h3>Kasarli</h3>
      <h4>1 porsiyon 35 TL</h4>   
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <div class="content">
      <img src="images/urunler/pideler/Kasarli_Kusbasili_Pide_V2.jpg" alt="" style="width:100%">
      <h3>Kasarli Kusbasili</h3>
      <h4>38 TL</h4>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <div class="content">
      <img src="images/urunler/pideler/Kasarli_Sucuklu_Pide_V2.jpg" alt="" style="width:100%">
      <h3>Kasarli Sucuklu</h3>
      <h4>45 TL</h4>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <div class="content">
      <img src="images/urunler/pideler/Kusbasili_Kapali_Pide_V2.jpg" alt="" style="width:100%">
      <h3>Kusbasili Kapali</h3>
      <h4>41 TL</h4>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <div class="content">
      <img src="images/urunler/pideler/Kiymali_Pide_V2.jpg" alt="" style="width:100%">
      <h3>Kiymali</h3>
      <h4>41 TL</h4>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <div class="content">
      <img src="images/urunler/pideler/Kusbasili_Pide_V2.jpg" alt="" style="width:100%">
      <h3>Kusbasili</h3>
      <h4>41 TL</h4>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <div class="content">
      <img src="images/urunler/pideler/Full_Karisik_Pide.jpg" alt="" style="width:100%">
      <h3>Full Karisik</h3>
      <h4>41 TL</h4>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <div class="content">
      <img src="images/urunler/pideler/Peynirli_yuvarlak.jpg" alt="" style="width:100%">
      <h3>Trabzon Peynirli</h3>
      <h4>41 TL</h4>
    </div>
  </div>
    <div class="column">
    <div class="content">
      <img src="images/urunler/pideler/kavurmali-yuvarlak.jpg" alt="" style="width:100%">
      <h3>Kavurmali</h3>
      <h4>41 TL</h4>
    </div>
  </div>
    <div class="column">
    <div class="content">
      <img src="images/urunler/pideler/sebzeli-yuvarlak_Pide.jpg" alt="" style="width:100%">
      <h3>Sebzeli</h3>
      <h4>41 TL</h4>
    </div>
  </div>
  
</div>
       </section>
       
       
  <!-- HAMBURGERLER  -->             
<section id="hamburgerler-content">
      
<div class="row">    
  <div class="column">
    <div class="content">
      <img src="images/urunler/hamburgerler/burger.jpg" alt="" style="width:100%">
      <h3>Hakkioglu Burger</h3>
      <h4>19.5 TL</h4>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <div class="content">
      <img src="images/urunler/hamburgerler/dubleburger.jpg" alt="" style="width:100%">
      <h3>Hakkioglu Duble Burger</h3>
      <h4>38 TL</h4>
    </div>
  </div>
  
</div>
</section>

</div>          
            
</div>
        
    <script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/popper.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/main.js"></script>


    </body>

</html>
```

### CSS

```
@charset "UTF-8";
/* CSS Document */


*{ 
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    line-height: 1.5;   
}

#sidebar {
    /*Strictly Necessary */
    position:fixed; 
    height: 100%;
    width:80px;
    margin: 0px;  

  /*Aesthetics*/
  background: #e85d1a; 
  border: 7px;  
}

#sidebar .active {
    min-width: 80px;
    max-width: 80px;
    
    text-align: center; }
    #sidebar.active ul.components li {
      font-size: 13px; }
      #sidebar.active ul.components li a {
        padding: 4px 0; }
        #sidebar.active ul.components li a span {
          margin-right: 0;
          display: block;
          font-size: 25px;
           }
          
      
#sidebar .logo {
    display: block;
    padding: 2px 1px;
    -webkit-transition: 0.3s;
    -o-transition: 0.3s;
    transition: 0.3s; }

#sidebar ul.components {
    padding: 0;
    -webkit-transition: 0.3s;
    -o-transition: 0.3s;
    transition: 0.3s; }
  
#sidebar ul li {
    font-size: 16px; }

#sidebar ul li > ul {
      margin-left: 10px; }
      #sidebar ul li > ul li {
        font-size: 14px; }

#sidebar ul li a {
      padding: 0px 30px;
      display: block;
      color: white;
      border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1); }

#sidebar ul li a span {
        margin-right: 15px; }
        
#sidebar a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
  color: green;
}

/* Add a color to the active/current link */
#sidebar a.active {
  background-color: #green;
  color: green;
}
        


#rightSideWrapper {
    /*Strictly Necessary */
    width: calc(100% - 80px);
    float: right;

    /*Aesthetics*/
    background: white;  
}

#header {
    /*Strictly Necessary */
    position: fixed;
    width: calc(100% - 80px);
    height: 60px; /*Adjust the hight to your purposes*/
    margin-left: 0px;
    
        
    /*Aesthetics*/
    background: #e85d1a;
    border-radius: 0px;
}


/* Add a black background color to the top navigation */
.topnav {

  border-radius: 3px;

}

/* Style the links inside the navigation bar */
.topnav a {
  float: left;
  color: #f2f2f2;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 8px 4px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 14px;
  display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
  
}

/* Change the color of links on hover */
.topnav a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
  color: black;
}

/* Add a color to the active/current link */
.topnav a.active {
  background-color: #04AA6D;
  color: white;
}

/* Right-left aligned section inside the top navigation */
.topnav-right {
  float: right;
}

.topnav.left {
 float:left;
}

/* Center website */

        
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6,
.h1, .h2, .h3, .h4, .h5, .h6 {
  margin-bottom: 0.5rem;
  font-weight: 500;
  line-height: 1.2; }

h1, .h1 {
  font-size: 2.5rem; }

h2, .h2 {
  font-size: 2rem;

        }

h3, .h3 {
  font-size: 1.5rem;
    display: inline;
      padding: 2px;
    
     }

h4, .h4 {
  font-size: 1.25rem;
    padding: 2px; }

h5, .h5 {
  font-size: 1.25rem; }

h6, .h6 {
  font-size: 1rem; }
  



hr {
  margin-top: 1rem;
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
  border: 0;
  border-top: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1); }
  
a {
  color: #007bff;
  text-decoration: none;
  background-color: transparent; }
  a:hover {
    color: #0056b3;
    text-decoration: underline; }

a:not([href]):not([tabindex]) {
  color: inherit;
  text-decoration: none; }
  a:not([href]):not([tabindex]):hover, a:not([href]):not([tabindex]):focus {
    color: inherit;
    text-decoration: none; }
  a:not([href]):not([tabindex]):focus {
    outline: 0; }
    
    
a {
  -webkit-transition: .3s all ease;
  -o-transition: .3s all ease;
  transition: .3s all ease;
  color: #3e64ff; }
  a:hover, a:focus {
    text-decoration: none !important;
    outline: none !important;
    -webkit-box-shadow: none;
    box-shadow: none; }
    
    li {
  list-style-type: none;
    }
    


/* Content */
.ContentBox{
    margin-top: 75px; /*The height of the   header*/
display: flex;

    flex-flow: row wrap;
    overflow: auto;
    padding-left: 5px;
    padding-right: 10px;

} 

.content {
  background-color: white;
  border-radius: 4px;  /* Rounded border */
  box-sizing: content-box;   
  border: 2px solid black;

}

.row {
padding: 2px;   

}

/* Add padding BETWEEN each column (if you want) */
.row,
.row > .column {

}

/* Create four equal columns that floats next to each other */
.column {
  float: left;
  width: 25%;
padding: 1px;
}

/* Clear floats after rows */
.row:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}

/* Responsive layout - makes a two column-layout instead of four columns */
@media screen and (max-width: 900px) {
  .column {
    width: 50%;
  }
}

/* Responsive layout - makes the two columns stack on top of each other instead of next to each other */
@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .column {
    width: 100%;
  }
}


img {
  
  
  width: 50px; /* Set a small width */
  
}

/* Add a hover effect (blue shadow) */
img:hover {
  box-shadow: 0 0 2px 1px red;
}

.logo img {
    height: 60px; width: 60px;
    text-decoration: none;
    border: none;
}

.headerimg img {
margin-top: 1px;
height: 57px; width: 100%;
border-radius: 0px;
}    

.haritaimg img {
margin-top: 1px;
height: 600px; width: 600px;
border-radius: 1px;
}    
 
 
{
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.headercolumn {
  float: left;
  width: 33.33%;
}

/* Clearfix (clear floats) */
.headerrow::after {
  content: "";
  clear: both;
  display: table;

}
```

### JavaScript

each section has its own show hide

```
$("#icecekler").click(function(){
    $("#main-content").hide()
    $("#izgaralar-content").hide()
    $("#pideler-content").hide()
    $("#hamburgerler-content").hide()
    $("#suluyemekler-content").hide()
    $("#salatalar-content").hide()
    $("#tatlilar-content").hide()
    $("#icecekler-content").show()
    $("#hakkimizda-content").hide()
    $("#iletisim-content").hide()
    $("#harita-content").hide()
    $("#calisma-content").hide()
})
```

Comment: Hi and Welcome to SO. please take the [tour] first. Then 
read [how to ask questions here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). After 
that edit the question to meet the guidelines and provide 
a [repro] for debugging details.

Comment: I notice that you include bootstrap js but not bootstrap css. Bootstrap css has in-built responsive features that you could take advantage of.

Answer (score 0):

- You have to define the **max-height** and set the **width to "auto"** so those images will become responsive based on height.

(First of all delete inner style width: 100%; inside <img elements and make classes look like this:)

https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_image_responsive.asp

```
.img {
    max-height: 60px;
    width: auto;
}
```

also try to use flexbox instead of static percentage definition (33% width etc.)... try this:

```
.headerrow {
    display: flex;
}

.headercolumn {
    flex-grow: 1; // eventual
}
```

https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/